# Laravel / MYSQL (Eloquent) - Querying large table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am making an online directory, this directory contains businesses, this is how the current table structure is set out:

1) "Business"

- ID (PK)
- Name
- Phone_Number
- Email

2) Tags

- id (PK)
- tag

3) Business_tags

- id (PK)
- business_id (FK)
- tag_id (FK)

There are over 9k rows inside of the business table, and over 84,269 rows and there are over 29k rows inside the ("Business_tags") table (As a business can have multiple tags).

Inside the business model, is the following:

```
public function tags()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tags');
}
```

The issue is when I am trying to do a search, so for example, let's say that someone wants to search for a "Chinese" then it's takes more time than it probably should to return a value. For example, I am using:

```
$business = Business::where(function ($business) use ($request) {

    $business->whereHas('tags', function ($tag) use ($request) {

    }); 

})->paginate(20);
```

Searching takes on average: 35 seconds to display the results.

Here is the raw sql:

```
select * from `businesses` where (exists (select * from `tags` inner join `business_tags` on `tags`.`id` = `business_tags`.`tags_id` where `business_tags`.`business_id` = `businesses`.`id` and `name` in ('chinese')))
```

This takes on average: 52.4s to run inside Sequel pro (Using the raw SQL statement)

Any ideas how I can improve the performance of this query so that it's a lot faster? I want to have this functionality, but the user is not going to wait this long for a response!

EDIT:

```
1   PRIMARY businesses  NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    8373    100.00  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  business_tags   NULL    ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    30312   10.00   Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  tags    NULL    eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   halalhands.business_tags.tags_id    1   10.00   Using where
```

Comment: You can use `chunk` this will faster your query

Comment: What indexes did you define?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I have set up index. I have set up foreign keys to each of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-complicating this, and not using eloquent relationships correctly.  You should be using JOINs instead:

```
$businesses = Business::join('business_tags', 'business_tags.business_id', '=', 'business.id')
                        ->join('tags', function($join) {
                            $join->on('business_tags.tag_id', '=', 'tags.id')
                                 ->where('tags.name', '=', 'chinese');
                        })->get();
```

Or in raw SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM `business`
INNER JOIN `business_tags` ON `business_tags`.`business_id` = `business`.`id`
INNER JOIN `tags` ON `business_tags`.`tag_id` = `tags`.`id` AND `tags`.`name` = 'chinese'
```

(Note that you could put that `tags.name = 'chinese'` part in the WHERE clause and yield the same effect)

Your current query does an exists subquery to get all the records from the pivot table that match the criteria, then passing that back to the main query.  It's an extra step, and it's unnatural.

Eloquent relationships are NOT for complex queries like this, but are rather there to provide additional, related information about a record without having to write another query manually.

For instance, if you want to view a business, you might query `with()` phone numbers and addresses from other tables.  You might want to list out their tags, or `sync()` them.  But eloquent does not build and filter queries, that's what query builder is for.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work.  I have, for example, 28k business_tags associated the the "tags_id" 1.. Running the query you gave me, just returns 1 row. Nothing else. I can't see any limits so what could be the issue? (Ran in laravel and sequal pro)

Comment: Also what does `business.business_id` refer to? As in the `business` table, there is just a column `id` and not `business_id`?

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer with the proper table names and some raw sql.  But other than that, this should work just fine.  How many tags do you have?  Honestly, 28k rows is not much for a pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

As a lot of others are also going to tell you.

1. Have you run `EXPLAIN` on your query?
2. Have you added indexes to your tables?
   Because even with the amount of data you have mentioned the query should have been faster than what you have reported.
3. Also see if a `JOIN` can work here and if faster?(just a thought)